# Sometimes pages for non logged in user are displayed for logged in user

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

After user registers and/or logs in, default page for logged in users is displayed. 
Though, sometimes, randomly, after user clicks logo and he goes back to home age, home page for non logged in users is displayed, while he's still logged in.
Refreshing the page solves the problem and home page for logged in users is displayed.
It's not a solution of course.
I have tried different approaches like deleting unnecessary plugins, clearing orphaned posts meta and tables, though still the problem comes back randomly.
No hosting caching and caching plugins are used (all were disabled and deleted to reduce noise)
There are expires directives in .htaccess for js, css and html.

Clueless how to find the root cause.

Comment: At this point, with no reference code and whatsoever, we can't see how you have set up different pages for logged in and non-logged in users. If you do give us something to look at, we could help you right away.

Comment: Another thing you can try, on the page for logged in users, before everything else, you should put a check if the user is logged in or not, if not then redirect to the page for non-logged in users, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that browser was caching the home page for logged out users on first access and displaying it sometimes even after a user has logged in.

The solution was to remove lines from `<IfModule mod_expires.c>` section in `.htaccess`:

```
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
```